# Build visual studio solution from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm writing a console application to get a solution from a tfs server, build it and publish on iis, but I'm stuck at building...

I found this code, which works like a charm

```
public static void BuildProject()
{
    string solutionPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\MySolution\Common\Common.csproj");

    List<ILogger> loggers = new List<ILogger>();
    loggers.Add(new ConsoleLogger());
    var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
    projectCollection.RegisterLoggers(loggers);
    var project = projectCollection.LoadProject(solutionPath);
    try
    {
        project.Build();
    }
    finally
    {
        projectCollection.UnregisterAllLoggers();
    }
}
```

but my solution it's pretty big and contains multiple projects which depends from each other (e.g. project A has a reference to project B)

how to get the correct order to build each project?
is there a way to build the entire solution from the .sln file?

Comment: If they're all in the same sollution, why would you link to eachother's dll rather than adding a project reference?

Comment: i mean that them are linked between each other, so i can't build a project without building another one before

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to code this buildrunner instead of just calling [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to build your solution? Together with the TFS PowerShell Cmdlets you'll have anything you need.

Comment: I want to know if there's a way to do this from code for learning reasons... If there's not, I will use `devenv /build Debug Solution.sln`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the following code to load a solution and compile it:

```
string projectFilePath = Path.Combine(@"c:\solutions\App\app.sln");

ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();

// THERE ARE A LOT OF PROPERTIES HERE, THESE MAP TO THE MSBUILD CLI PROPERTIES
Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
globalProperty.Add("OutputPath", @"c:\temp");

BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc);
BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFilePath, globalProperty, "4.0", new string[] { "Build" }, null);
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS - IN PROCESS MSBUILD
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest);
// A SIMPLE WAY TO CHECK THE RESULT
if (buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
{              
    //...
}
```

Comment: yeah, i found that code on http://bogdangavril.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/take-control-of-msbuild-using-msbuild-api/ me too... but it doesn't work. It fails always, even if i can build manaully the solution from visual studio ide

Comment: Are all your used projects in your solution? Did you add all your referenced dll's (from your own projects in the solution) through Add References/Projects? I've compiled a rather big solution like this ...

Comment: In your example your compiling a csproj not a sln, typo?

Comment: it's not a typo, i can build a single project with that code but i want to build the whole solution at once, if possible

Comment: I used the sln and that worked, did you try adding a logger to see which error the build is throwing?

Comment: Did you check your GlobalProperties, for example wrong use of Platform  (if you use x86 instead of Any CPU) can cause build to fail.

Comment: Try GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU"); with a space between Any and CPU.

Comment: i found what it may cause the error: the output path is a "global" /bin/debug. but i need to have a /bin/debug folder for each project in my solution